# Bash init script skips reading commands in if loop

Tags: bash, shell, startup, init, rhel6

I am trying to create an init script for a program in bash. (rhel6)

It checks for the processes first. If processes are found it will echo that program is already online and if not it'll move on to to start the program as a certain user by using launch script. After doing that it should tail the log file of the program and check for a string of words together. If the words are found it should kill tail and echo that program is online.

Here's the start segment.

```
prog=someProg
user=someUser
threadCount=$(ps -ef | grep $prog |grep -v 'grep' |awk '{ print $2 }'| wc -l)

startb() {
  if [ "$threadCount" -eq 2 ]; then
    echo "$prog already online."
  else
    echo "Bringing $prog online."
    su $user -c "/path/to/start/script.sh"
    tail -f /path/to/$prog/log/file |
      while IFS=$'\n' read line
        do
          if [[ $line == *started\ up\ and\ registered\ in* ]]; then
            pkill tail
            echo "$prog now online."
          fi
        done
  fi
}
```

My problems:

1. The variable **$prog** doesn't get picked in **$threadcount** no
   matter how I try. (with single and double quotes)
2. The logic about tailing the log file works randomly. Some times it
   just works perfect. It tails and waits till the string is found
   before echoing program is online and at times it just starts script
   and then echoes that program is online without the tail or wait.

It's unpredictable. I implemented the same logic in stop segment too to monitor log and then echo but even that works the same way as start. Just random.

I am sure that this might look dumb and broken. This is made by picking pieces here and there with my beginner bash skills.

Thanks in advance for suggestions and help.

Comment: `pkill tail` would attempt to kill all tails. I know that is not your question, just an observation.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the error you are experiencing with the "grep $prog"...sorry.

But for the other part.

1. I will assume that the script starting your program, the line with su, is starting something in background and that the script end by itself. If not, your example will wait indefinitely.
2. Could be a personal preference, but when I'm using something like tail to verify lines, I use a named pipe (mkfifo).

That would give something like :

```
# Getting the tail in background
tail -f /path/to/$prog/log/file > some_fifo &
# Getting the tail PID
tailPID=$!

while read line; do #You don't need to modify/use IFS here.
     if [[ $line == *started\ up\ and\ registered\ in* ]]; then
           kill -15 $tailPID #since you know the PID you won't kill another tail
           echo "$prog now online."
           break # don't like the possibility, even remote, of an infinite loop :)
     fi
done < some_fifo #reading from the named pipe
```

Hope it can help you

Comment: Thank you very much for your input Andre!

Your guess is right. It's just command to start java program with load of arguments and then it throws everything to dev null.

For the first one I'm not getting any error. 
Let's just say I declare variable $prog=someProg and when I use the command..
ps -ef | grep $prog
..as expected it should do this..
ps -ef| grep someProg

But it is literally grepping for $prog and echoes that program is not running.
As obviously there's no program running with that name.

Thanks once again!